# Add item to top of menu using a filter in functions.php

Tags: php, functions, menus, filters, menu-order

I want to add a logo to my main menu. I am using this function:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_logo_to_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function add_logo_to_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
    if ($args->menu == 'main-menu') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="#"><img src="PATH_TO_IMAGE"></a></li>';
    }

    return $items;
}
```

The problem I am having is I want the logo to be at the top of the menu. This filter currently places it in the last position of the menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$items = 'Blah'.$items` instead of `$items .= 'Blah'`

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_logo_to_menu_item', 10, 2 );

function add_logo_to_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

    if ($args->menu == 'main-menu') {
        $items = '<li><a href="#"><img src="PATH_TO_IMAGE"></a></li>' . $items;
    }

    return $items;

}
```